# Return relationships in Laravel show route

Tags: php, laravel

When I create a CRUD controller, this is the show route created by default:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Team  $team
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Team $team)
{
    //
}
```

`$team` is an object here, an instance of `Team`. If I do this I have the correct object passed to blade:

```
public function show(Team $team)
{
    return view('admin.teams.show', ['team' => $team]);
}
```

But, `Team` has a many-to-many relationship with another model called `Player`, and this relationship is defined as such from the `Team` side:

```
public function players() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Player::class);
}
```

In my show method, I'd like to return the $team with its related players. But since $team is already an object and not a query builder, it's too late to do something like

```
$team->with('players')
```

So how do I get the related players here? I know I can do something like:

```
public function show(Team $team)
{
    $team_extended = Team::where('id', $team['id'])->with('players')->first();
    return view('admin.teams.show', ['team' => $team_extended]);
}
```

But it feels like hacking a functionality that should be there by default. Is there a built-in Laravel way to do this or am I just inventing hot water and should take the approach I used in my solution above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already got your `Team` model loaded, you can load a relationship without having to completely re-create it using the `->load()` method:

```
public function show(Team $team){
  $team->load("players");
  return view("admin.teams.show", ["team" => $team]);
}
```

Note however, this isn't required unless you need to modify the default content of `$team->players`. When you trying to access `$team->players` say in your `admin.teams.show` view, if that property doesn't already exist (as it would using `->with(["players"])` or `->load("players")`, Laravel will load it automatically.

Comment: Ah. Understood. It didn't occur to me that Laravel would just load the relationship requested from the template.

Comment: Yup, Laravel is handy like that. There are instances where you would want to re-query, but it would be more efficient to do something like `$players = $team->players()->where(...)...` and pass as a separate variable. Or, modify the route to pass a `teamId` instead of a `Team`, and construct on page load. Etc etc.